# populate select in Laravel form with value from model

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, populate

I made form with select. Here is code:

```
{!! Form::model($customerAccount, ['route' => ['admin.customerAccount.update', 
$customerAccount->id_customer_account], 'method' => 'PUT', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
```

...

```
<div class="@if ($errors->has('cacct_active'))has-error has-feedback @endif form-group">
    {!! Form::label('cacct_active', 'Status: *',['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-8">
           {!! Form::select('cacct_active',$customerAccount->getStatusList(),null,['class'=> 
              'form-control', 'required' => 'required', 'autofocus' => 'none']) !!}
        </div>
</div>
```

I have options loaded by $customerAccount->getStatusList() and want default selected option to be value from my object. But it does not happen, selected is just the first one from options.

---

**EDIT**

the problem was I was using 'true, false' values in db and then '0, 1' values in 'statusList' parameter - the easiest way to solve this was to use mutator 'casts' in model for this field

Comment: All you need to do is pass default selected value in the third argument :)

Comment: this place where now is 'null'? as a string or array?

Comment: Does the `customerAccount` model have a `cacct_active` field ?

Comment: In the place of null, pass an element of `$customerAccount->getStatusList()` !!